# Прилипающий футер к низу страницы

Tags: html, css

Приветствую.

Есть, допустим, такая разметка:

```
<header>
</header>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="contentwrapper"></div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Стили:

```
html, body, #wrap {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
body > #wrap {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#contentwrapper {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
        width:100%;
    background-color:#42484d;
    min-height:50px;
    padding:25px 0 0;
}
```

Вроде бы, все работает, но, если открыть, например, firebug, то футер уезжает вверх вместе с ним. Как можно исправить это?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вроде бы и работает, но не совсем. Футер снизу, но за пределами окна браузера.

Более традиционный вариант такой:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
footer {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

здесь мы делаем в нижней части контентной области отступ, на место которого разместим футер. Сам же футер располагается после контентной области, имеющей минимальную высоту 100%, и сдвигается вверх на величину собственной высоты. border-box задаётся, чтобы отступ не увеличивал высоту контентной области.

Comment: @Елена Левина, спасибо, но, вроде как, все равно уезжает. 

http://jsfiddle.net/qeER7/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такой вариант: [Pure sticky footer](http://grigoriev.pw/articles/pure-sticky-footer/)

HTML:

`<body>
    <header class="header">...</header>
    <main class="main">...</main>
    <footer class="footer">...</footer>
</body>`

CSS:

```
html{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin-bottom: 150px; 
}

.footer{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```